# Is this a valid css?

Tags: css, anchor

I have a pager in my page with anchors in it... I use the following css...

```
.page-numbers a {
color:#808185; cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none;outline:none;
}
.page-numbers a:hover {
text-decoration:underline;
}
.page-numbers a:visited {
color:#808185;outline:none;
}
```

But my anchor tag doesn't seem to take the css above instead it uses the css below,

```
a {
color:#0077CC; cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none;outline:none;
}
a:hover {
text-decoration:underline;
}
a:visited {
color:#4A6B82;outline:none;
}
```

Which i have given in the top of my stylesheet... Any suggestion...

Comment: are you sure "page numbers" the class name of the parent container element?

Comment: Most browsers these days have a developer toolbar/menu (or firebug for firefox) that allows you to inspect elements to see what styles are being applied to an element and which are being overwritten. My advice is to get friendly with the one in your particular browser.

Comment: @zx12r `pager` is the parent container not `page numbers`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selector `.page-numbers a` means "an anchor tag inside a tag with the class `page-numbers`", e.g.:

```
<div class="page-numbers"><a>This would match</a></div>
```

If you mean an anchor tag **with** the class `page-numbers`, use:

```
a.page-numbers {
    color:#808185; cursor:pointer; text-decoration:none;outline:none;
}
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your links are under a container with page-numbers class?

Are you sure your stylesheet is linked to the page correctly?

Are you sure its not link with page-numbers class? In that case you'll have to use a.page-numbers css selector to target the link.